# Find max number of molecules

Tags: java, if-statement

Find the max number of molecules that it is possible to create
H2SO4 so for 1 molecule is needed:
-2 atoms of H
-1 atom of S
-4 atoms of O

This code gives me just one possible molecule, but it is possible to create more

```
public static void numOdMol(int hydrogen, int oxygen, int sulfur) {
    int counter=0;
    if (  hydrogen >= 2 && oxygen >= 1 && sulfur >= 4) {
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}

public static void main(String[] agrs) {
    Test.numOdMol(5, 7, 35);
}
```

Comment: With your `counter++` logic in place you need to loop until the condition is false and decrement the different element counters while incrementing the molecule counter.

Comment: Alternatively divide sulfur by 1, oxygen by 4, hydrogen by 2 and then pick the minimum number of all three values to get the number of molecules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are just checking if a single molecule can be constructed. Also note that your condition is wrong since H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> needs 2 hydrogen, 1 sulfur and 4 oxygen atoms.

###### Calculative approach with `Math.min(...)`

One option is to determine which element is used up first by dividing the available number of atoms by the required number for a molecule. Then round down (floor) this and take the minimum of the 3 elements.

```java
public static void numOdMol(int hydrogen, int oxygen, int sulfur) {
    int counter = Math.min(hydrogen/2, Math.min(oxygen/4, sulfur/1));
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

###### Calculative approach with `IntStream`

An elegant way to use the calculative approach is with an *IntStream* which is extendable and easy to read.

```java
public static void numOdMol(int hydrogen, int oxygen, int sulfur) {
    int counter = IntStream.of(
            hydrogen / 2,
            oxygen / 4,
            sulfur / 1
    ).min().getAsInt();
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

###### Loop approach

Another option is looping as long as enough atoms are available to construct a molecule while incrementing a counter.

```java
public static void numOdMol(int hydrogen, int oxygen, int sulfur) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (hydrogen >= 2 && oxygen >= 4 && sulfur >= 1) {
        hydrogen -= 2;
        oxygen -= 4;
        sulfur -= 1;
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Comment: I would prefer `Math.min(Math.min(hydrogen / 2, oxygen / 4), sulfur / 1)` over using streams for something that really is not at all a stream.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks, I added this approach as well which is the shortest way to write it. For molecules with many more elements, I personally would prefer the stream approach as it is very easy to read.